# Importing Cordova plugins into Worklight 6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I worked through the ApacheCordovaPlugin example. Its nice to see that creating a new plugin is possible, and I successfully replicated the HelloWorldPlugin in a WL project of my own just to make sure I could get all the plumbing to work. It is tricky, you have to make entries in the right XML files, name your Java and .js files appropriately, know how to include them and call the functions, etc. If you make a mistake there is very little information visible that you can use to debug it. The entire process is very fragile.

Now I would like to have access to the large library of existing Cordova plugins. My primary development target is Android. I downloaded a plugin zip file from a git repository and extracted it. Looking at the files and the directory layout it is not at all clear how to integrate this into a WL project. Cordova has a 'plugin.xml' file that appears to supply all the glue, but there is no such thing in WL. I was not able to determine where to put files and what edits to make in the Worklight project that would cause the Cordova plugin to be recognized and accessed from my application JavaScript.

Surely this process is possible and is documented somewhere? Ideally there would be a utility that we use to import Cordova plugins, but next-best would be a step-by-step procedure description. I saw one somebody did for getting plugins into the iOS application environment, but not Android.

Comment: Have you been able to accomplish importing existing plugins to worklight ?
I've been struggling with this same problem (using WL7)

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you've downloaded a plugin for cordova 3.0+. Since latest WL contains Cordova 2.6 you need to download plugin for this (or similar) version. E.g. if you're talking about barcode scanner plugin the most suitable version would be 2.2 (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner)